# Update field with no-value

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table in a *PostgreSQL* database.
I'm writing data to this table (using some computation with *Python* and `psycopg2` to write results down in a specific column in that table).

I need to update some existing cell of that column.
Till now, I was able either to delete the complete row before writing this single cell because all other cells on the row were also written back as the same time, or delete the entire column for the same reason.

Now I can't do that anymore because that would mean long computation time to rebuild either the row or the column for only a few new values to be written in some cell.

I know the `update` command. It works well for that.
But, if I had existing values in some cells, and that a new computation gives me no more result for these cells, I would like to "clear" the existing values to keep the table up-to-date with the last computation I've done.

Is there a simple way to do that ? `update` doesn't seems to work (it seems to keep the old values).
I precise again I'm using `psycopg2` to write things to my table.

Comment: Show data, code and desired final result.

Answer (score 1):

you simple update the cell with the value NULL in SQL - psycopg2 will insert NULL into the database when you update your column with None-type from python.

Comment: How would do this within Python?
I guess it would be a mess for me as I only call the function that write to DB when values exist.

Comment: `cur.execute("UPDATE tableX (col1, col3) VALUES (%s, %s) WHERE id=%s", (100, None, 123))`

something like this - a normal update statement, this one would update the row with id=123 and set col1 to 100 and deletes the value from col3. col2 is unaffected.